# Maven - get list of provided/optional dependencies from project dependencies

Tags: maven

Sorry if the title is confusing, couldn't think of a better way to word it, so probably best to ask using an example.

In a project that I'm working on cleaning up, using mvn dependency:analyze, commons-fileupload is listed as dependency that is unused. Removing it ended up breaking things, and the reason was because some parts of primefaces require it, and it's listed in the primefaces pom as a "provided" dependency. My question, as such, is if there's a plugin, or otherwise easy way to sort of scan all of my declared dependencies' poms for declared optional or provided-scope dependencies (basically so I can see "Oh, even though my code isn't using commons-fileupload, this library might be, so I should leave it in.)

Comment: This is usually not necessary because they case you mentioned is really rare.